# image crousel not working onsenui

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, onsen-ui

i have image Carousel work perfectly when loaded in browser as separate page ,when the same page called from index.html its not work

```
<ons-navigator>
  <ons-tabbar>
    <ons-tab page="home.html" label="Home" icon="home" active="true"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="page1.html" label="page1" icon="fa fa-desktop"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="page2.html" label="page2" icon="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab  label="page3.html" icon="page3"   ></ons-tab>
    <ons-tab page="contact.html" label="Contact" icon="phone"></ons-tab>
  </ons-tabbar>
</ons-navigator>
```

when i load page3.html in browser the Carousel work perfectly ,

i used this https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

when i call from application it will not work, am new to onsenui , please help

Answer (score 0):

The way you write your code is not correct. Please modify it as follows:

```
<ons-navigator>
    <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="home"
            label="Home"
            page="home.html"
            active="true"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="fa fa-desktop"
            label="page1"
            page="page1.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="fa fa-bar-chart-o"
            label="page2"
            page="page2.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="gear"
            label="page3"
            page="page3.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item
            icon="phone"
            label="Contact"
            page="contact.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>
</ons-navigator>
```

I've tested and it works fine.

Comment: the code above works perfect without issues , also i got the Carousel got worked with above code itself